# Access Report.IsLoaded=true SubReport.IsLoaded=false, why?

Tags: ms-access-reports

Hello to all and thanks in advance.  I have a Report which gives a list of all projects and then a subreport in the Report Footer that sums the Project Costs over each department.  I am trying to access data in that subreport but every time I try:

```
 yr_strt=me.sbrptProposalSummary.Report.lblFY1.caption
```

I get "Run-time error '2455': You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report.

Then I tried:

```
 yr_strt=Reports("sbrptProposalOverview").lblFY1.Caption
```

and I get the error (2451) that the report name is misspelled or refers to a report that isn't open or does't exist.

Which led me to the IsLoaded:

```
Debug.Print Application.CurrentProject.AllReports("rptProposalOverview").IsLoaded
Debug.Print Application.CurrentProject.AllReports("sbrptProposalOverview").IsLoaded
```

and I get True and False respectively.  What's the deal? So frustrated right now!

Thank You!
Jessica

Comment: Access 2010 and I open the report in acViewReport mode.

Answer (score 0):

Jessica - In what event/form is this statement?  yr_strt=me.sbrptProposalSummary.Report.lblFY1.caption

Could it be the form isn't loaded when this line is hit?

Excellent coding though!  Love to see those calls instead of trying easier and less efficient methods.

Stay frustrated!  It is the primary symptom of learning! :)

Comment: Hi Jim, this would've been better in a comment rather than an answer. Read this page for more information on answering questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: This is code that is running when a command button is hit that resides in the report header.  That's the frustrating part, Access is saying the subreport isn't loaded but I am looking right at it and it's parent report .IsLoaded=True!  How can a parent report be loaded but not the child report?